# Classpath not working when running Scala script

Tags: scala, scala-cli

I have a successfully compiled a Java class called `bnc.Encryption` in my lib directory: `/Users/satchwinston/Development/test/lib`.

I'm using Java 21 and Scala 3.3.1, I'm NOT using the Metals extension.

I execute my Scala script like this: `./encryptor` which in turns runs `scala -explain -classpath "/Users/satchwinston/Development/test/lib"`

I get the following result:

```
-- [E006] Not Found Error: /Users/satchwinston/Development/test/scala-cli/src/main/scala/./encryptor:7:7 
7 |import bnc.Encryption
  |       ^^^
  |       Not found: bnc
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Explanation (enabled by `-explain`)
  |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  | The identifier for `bnc` is not bound, that is,
  | no declaration for this identifier can be found.
  | That can happen, for example, if `bnc` or its declaration has either been
  | misspelt or if an import is missing.
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 error found
Errors encountered during compilation
```

Here is my encryptor Scala script:

```scala
#!/usr/bin/env scala -explain -classpath "/Users/satchwinston/Development/test/lib"
/* $Id$ */

import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

import bnc.Encryption

val usage = """
  Usage: encryptor ([-e] | [-d]) ([-in filename] | <arg>) > <filename>
"""

def encrypt(string: String): String =
  Encryption.encrypt(string)

def decrypt(string: String): String =
  Encryption.decrypt(string)

@main def encryptor(args: String*): Unit =
  if (args.isEmpty || args.length != 2 || args.length != 3) {
    println(usage)
    sys.exit(1)
  }

  val e: Boolean = args(0) == "-e"
  val d: Boolean = args(0) == "-d"
  val in: String = if (args(1) == "-in") args(2) else ""
  val str: String = if (args(1) != "-in") args(1) else ""

  if (e && str.length() > 0)
    println(encrypt(str))
  else if (e)
    println(encrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
  else if (d && str.length > 0)
    println(decrypt(str))
  else if (d)
    println(decrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
  else {
    println(usage)
    sys.exit(1)
  }

  sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Could you please be clear about how you are running the script

Comment: Is the BNC class in a JAR or directly a `.class` file? If it's a class file, I have a doubt if it must follow the package and be named `bnc/Encryption.class` (thus be in a subfolder). Maybe worth trying.

Comment: I run the script by typing ./encryptor (the shebang enables me to omit the scala extension in the file name. Also one of the reasons for using Scala is because it can be executed from source and not compiled. This is not prehistoric. Scripting in this way is often used as sort of glue code for large complex systems programming. We will be using a mix of standard Java and Scala)

Comment: The BNC class is not in a jar. I've tried using a jar but the same thing happens. When I'm ready to use it in a real system then we will certainly use jar files.

Comment: Shell scripts, PHP, Python, ...etc. are not compiled either. Why do you think the powers that be added this functionality to Scala? Scala-Cli is a feature of the language.

Comment: Sure if you want to use **Scala** as a scripting language, use **Scala-cli** not manually compiling and running `.class` files.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think you might be unaware that `scala` IS Scala CLI. See https://virtuslab.com/blog/scala-cli-the-new-scala-runner/ - in newest versions of scala packages (as in global scala installation from package manager) when you type `scala` into command like you are running scala-cli just with some options disabled by default (until they will be deemed production ready and enabled as well.). So his `#!/usr/bin/env scala` IS running Scala CLI as advertised.

Comment: Here is the information about making Scala CLI new default implementation of `scala` - https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/scala-cli.html and https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/sip-46-scala-cli-as-default-scala-command/5996

Comment: If they are using **scala-cli** then just import files the **scala-cli** way.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I rechecked and I was wrong about a few things. I posted an answer showing the scala cli way without these errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make your script work like this:

```
// bnc/Encryption.java - stub since I do not know your implementation
package bnc;

public class Encryption {

  public static String encrypt(String s) { return s; }
  public static String decrypt(String s) { return s; }
}
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S scala-cli shebang --server=false
//> using scala 3.3.1
//> using option -explain
//> using jvm zulu-jre:21.0.0
//> using file bnc/Encryption.java

import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

import bnc.Encryption

val usage = """
  Usage: encryptor ([-e] | [-d]) ([-in filename] | <arg>) > <filename>
"""

def encrypt(string: String): String =
  Encryption.encrypt(string)

def decrypt(string: String): String =
  Encryption.decrypt(string)

def encryptor(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  if (args.isEmpty || args.length != 2 || args.length != 3) {
    println(usage)
    sys.exit(1)
  }

  val e: Boolean = args(0) == "-e"
  val d: Boolean = args(0) == "-d"
  val in: String = if (args(1) == "-in") args(2) else ""
  val str: String = if (args(1) != "-in") args(1) else ""

  if (e && str.length() > 0)
    println(encrypt(str))
  else if (e)
    println(encrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
  else if (d && str.length > 0)
    println(decrypt(str))
  else if (d)
    println(decrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
  else {
    println(usage)
    sys.exit(1)
  }

  sys.exit(0)

encryptor(args)
```

Addressing what you wrote:

1. if you have Scala CLI you do NOT NEED another Scala installation. It is an all in one package: scala + scalac + build tool, the *replacement* for several older tools.
2. Scala version can be changed both by [a flag](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/commands/compile/#scala-version) as well as [a directive](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/directives/#scala-version)
3. You need to use `.scala` extension if you are building a "program" rather than a "script" - programs have entrypoints which tells JVM where to start (`@main`), while scripts evaluate everything from top to the bottom within a file you are executing (so they do not need any main). Remove `@main`, and call your method yourself with `args` and you return to "script" mode

   - in case anyone is interested why `@main` exists if Scala CLI is for scripts: it is not only for scripts. Create several `.scala` files in a directory, in 1 of them (preferably `project.scala`) put `using` directives with Scala version, JVM version, platform, dependencies, etc. Then `scala-cli compile .` will build a normal project, which would need an entrypoint if you did `scala-cli run .`. These Scala files do need the `.scala` extension.
   - however, single Scala files evaluated from the top to the bottom, not intended to be distributed as JARs nor opened in IDEs, (optionally referring other `.scala` or `.java` files), can be written as scripts, where their whole body is a main of sort. These files use `.sc` extension, although with a shebang you can also use no extension at all
4. JVM version can be changed both by [a flag](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/cli-options/#--jvm) as well as [a directive](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/directives/#jvm-version). Scala CLI uses coursier and its `coursier java --available` allows printing all versions that can be used there. Bloop makes sure that you are using a [server to keep JVM warm](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/guides/internals/#bloop) between consecutive calls. You can disable it with [a `--server=false` flag](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/cli-options/#--server).
5. and 6. - your personal stylistic preferences are a non-technical issue. Also: you don't need to use `-classpath` or `--classpath` - there is [an `--extra-jars` flag](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/cli-options/#--extra-jars) for adding JARs (or `.class`es) to the runtime, as well as [`//> using jar`/`//> using jars`](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/directives/#custom-jar) directive for adding a JAR. Because a situation where you have a standalone `.class` which is not a part of JAR but also there is no source (which you could add with `//> using file filename.java`) is rather rare.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently the scala-cli way of doing things is not up to speed yet:

1. I had to install scala-cli separately from my Scala installation.
2. The scala-cli is only at version 3.3.0. My scala installation is at 3.3.1.
3. I have to use the .scala extension in the scripts filename.
4. The JVM in the ridiculous "bloop" server is using Java 17. My Java installation is using Java 21. Can't figure out how to change JVM. Why the heck do I need a "bloop" server?
5. I have to use this ridiculous thing instead of a normal shebang:
   #!/usr/bin/env -S scala-cli shebang -S 3
6. It looks like you got to use --classpath not -classpath. No --cp? Get real.

Hmmmm. Maybe Groovy is a better option.

Comment: Ad 1) if you have scala-cli you don't need another "Scala installation"; ad 2) https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/directives/#scala-version; ad 3) you only need .scala if you want `@main` - call `args` directly and you can skip it; ad 4) https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/directives/#jvm-version and https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/guides/internals/#bloop and https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/cli-options/#--server ; ad 5) and 6) - that's completely non-technical and doesn't block you at anything.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Currently scala-cli is not suitable for real world development.

Comment: Ridiculous why? Because it achieves your goals in a different way you assumed? Scala version CAN be selected, JVM CAN be selected, bloop CAN be disabled. Complaining that shebang looks ugly or that there is `--classpath` instead of `-classpath` sounds more like a childish tantrum than a technical issue.

Comment: There should not be a separate scala-cli and scala installation. I got the bloop thing working using scala-cli bloop exit; scala-cli --power bloop start --jvm 21;

Comment: I also added "-S 3.3.1" to my scala script shebang and that works. I guess I don't need to use the @main. I cans use "object encryptor { def main(..." So thanks. But it still doesn't make use of my --classpath "~/Development/test/test.jar". I get a class not found error on my import statement.  I've the same problem with a Groovy script so this is not a scala-cli problem. It's a problem with my environment that I'm stuck on.

Comment: The `scala` was an old runner that many people complained was not good enough. Scala CLI is developed as a replacement and it was NOT put into main Scala because people were worried that old scripts build on top of hack would stop working. `scala` and `scalac` are effectively "deprecated" runners, maintained for legacy reasons and ties to a particular Scala version. Scala CLI is NOT tied to a Scala version (it has its own release lifecycle) as it allows to select: Scala, JVM, etc.libraries, compiler plugins, etc.

Comment: Put this .class into a separate JAR or copy source to the directory with Scala CLI and you'll be able to use Scala CLIs directives to add .java file or JAR. With `--server=false` it will surely use the new JVM (that you select with `using jvm` or --jvm), then issues with your Java environment will not propagate there.

Comment: Thanks. So scala-cli is the proper way to do this. I've got Scala working now. Now I've got to get Groovy working too.

Comment: ad 5) there is a `shebang` command:
https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/commands#shebang

Comment: ad 4) you can disable bloop using `--server=false`